# Equalizer in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

Im running a copy of WordPress and loaded in the Zurb Foundation Press and seems the normal elements are all working however im also using the Visual Composer plugin and wanted to create equal height columns for my content, i thought it might be possible to do with foundations equalizer option as it should already be present with Foundation Press. The documentation uses attributes as the way of setting it up with a equalizer on the row and equalizer-watch attributes on the columns. VC allows custom classes to be added so i was wondering if its possible to set the attributes as classes rather and how would i go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely the solution i was asking for but ive dont this by using flexbox on the row and columns as classes in VC.

```
/* Place on Row - Parent */
.equalizer-parent {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

/* Place on Column - Child */
.equalizer-content {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```